# How to Bind Database Value to TextBox Dynamically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF.
When i click the button a dynamic TextBox will show.
Whenever the textbox is focused it will display a gridview.
That gridview contains a table of values.
When i enter one row it will bind to the textbox, but when the gridview shows after entering the values it does not show the new values.

```
 int count = 0;       
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.MinHeight = 15;
        t.Width = 100;
        t.Height = 30;
        t.Name = "txtPKSourceCode";
        t.Text = "{Binding  PurchaseOrder.PickupSrcCodeName, Mode=TwoWay}";
        ColumnDefinition colDef1;
        colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
       mymy.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);

        RowDefinition rowDef1;
        rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
        mymy.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
        ++count;

        mymy.Children.Add(t);
          Grid.SetColumn(t, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(t, count);
  t.GotFocus += t_GotFocus;

     }

    private void t_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        SourceCodeDialog sourcedlg = new SourceCodeDialog("txtPKSourceCode");
        sourcedlg.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
        sourcedlg.POWindow = this;
        var srcresult = sourcedlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create object of Binding class where you can specify your Binding Path and Mode. Then you can use SetBinding() method to set the binding to the textbox.

TextBox t = new TextBox();

Binding txtBinding = new Binding("PurchaseOrder.PickupSrcCodeName");
txtBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

t.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, txtBinding);

Comment: thank you very much fo display.but in this way old textbox value binding here i need new value insert in gridview values

Comment: <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SourceEntryCtrlGotFocus}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>  how to givee this code to dynamic textbox